# how can i do setter for decorator @myownproperties

Tags: python, python-decorators

i am trying to do my own property but i can't understand how to implement method set.
this command x.value = 20 doesnt work. how can i do setter for decorator @myownproperties?

```
 class myownproperties:

    def __init__(self, dget, dset=None):
        self.dget = dget
        self.dset = dset

    def __get__(self, obj, klass = None):
        return self.dget.__get__(obj, klass)()

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        type_ = type(obj)
        return self.dset.__get__(obj, type_)(value)

    def setter(self, func):
        self.dset = classmethod(func)
        return self


class Foo:

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    @myownproperties
    def value(self):
        return self.foo

    @value.setter
    def value_setter(self, new_val):
        self.foo = new_val

x = Foo(10)
print(x.value)
x.value = 20
print(x.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version:

```
class myownproperties:
    def __init__(self, dget, dset=None):
        self.dget = dget
        self.dset = dset

    def __get__(self, obj, _cls):
        return self.dget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.dset(obj, value)

    def setter(self, func):
        self.dset = func
        return func


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    @myownproperties
    def value(self):
        return self.foo

    @value.setter
    def value_setter(self, new_val):
        self.foo = new_val


x = Foo(10)
print(x.value)  # 10
x.value = 20
print(x.value)  # 20
```

I couldn't figure out the purpose behind wrapping `dset` in `classmethod` or in calling `__get__` on the resulting object, so I just removed all that and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

At the time the decorator is applied, and within that scope, `def value_setter(self, new_val):` is just an ordinary function. (We aren't looking it up on an instance of the class, so there is no opportunity for method binding to occur.) So in the decorator's `setter` method, we should just have `self.dset = func`, just like how we have just `self.dget = dget` in the `__init__`.

When the `__set__` of the descriptor is called, we should directly invoke this function, because it's the function that contains the logic for what should happen upon the attribute access. That is, just `self.dset(obj, value)` - here, `self` is the descriptor; its `dset` attribute (a *function* which is stored in the object, not a bound method) is looked up and called with `obj` as the `Foo` instance and `value` as the value to set. The function takes in `self, obj` where `self` is bound to the `Foo` instance - not by method-call binding, but by normal argument passing. The setter does `self.foo = new_val`, thus assigning the `foo` attribute of the `Foo` instance.

Similarly for `__get__` - just use `self.dget` directly, and `return` the result.

Putting these pieces together gives Samwise's version of the code.

---

(Incidentally, in case you weren't aware: method binding, itself, uses this mechanism! Functions are descriptors; their class implements `__get__` to do the binding and create an object that represents the bound method, which can then be called.)